# Получение URL пакета

Tags: debian, apt-get

Требуется по названию пакета получить его URL для скачки, нашел такой вариант:

```
apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq $package | cut -d"'" -f2 | grep "/$package_"
```

Вариант вполне рабочий, но очень медленный, на получение 1 URL требуется примерно 0.8 секунд, а мне необходимо получить URL десятков тысяч пакетов, поэтому требуется значительно быстрее вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

конечно, лучше искать среди закешированной информации, т.е., использовать программу *apt-cache* (получив предварительно актуальный список пакетов командой `{apt|apt-get|aptitude} update`):

```
$ apt-cache show bash | sed -n 's/^Filename: //p'
pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.4-5_amd64.deb
```

и, естественно, быстрее будет вызвать программу один раз, передав ей список пакетов, нежели вызывать по разу на каждый пакет.

---

пример. установлено в системе:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | wc -l
2242
```

время на получение списка:

```
$ time apt-cache show $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print$1}') | sed -n 's/^Filename: //p' >/dev/null

real    0m0.709s
user    0m0.320s
sys 0m0.416s
```

Comment: Вроде отлично работает, но заметил одну странность, количество строк в результате превышает количество пакетов, вот например: `aptitude search -F "%p" '?tag(role::program)' | wc -l` - 7404
`apt-cache show $(aptitude search -F "%p" '?tag(role::program)') | sed -n 's/^Filename: //p' | wc -l` - 7483

Comment: несколько версий пакетов бывает в репозитории. добавьте опцию `--no-all-versions`, чтобы отображать только версию-кандидат на установку.